# PyCharm | Function myFunction at 0x000001EBF0C97B70

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm starting with Python functions and I think that I'm not getting something. When I run the program there isn't no error, or syntax error —usually in red in Python—. But neither is working, I just got the answer 'function hello at 0x000001EBF0C97B70'. I think that is something related to the syntax.

```
def hello(name):  # <----- parametro
    hello('Alice')    # <----- argumento
    if name == 'Alice':
        return 'holaaa alice'
print(hello)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the *function*. But what you want to do is *call* the function and print the *value it returns*:

```
print(hello("Alice"))
```

But don't do that until you have removed the line

```
hello('Alice')    # <----- argumento
```

from the function. It doesn't belong inside the function, but outside. If you call `hello()` with that line in it from inside `hello()` you will get infinite recursion.